# kotlin, how to get sub list by its position

Tags: kotlin, filter

Having a list

```
val list = toList(1,2,3,4,5,6...)
```

would like to have a sub list from it which has only items at certain known position, i.e. position at 1, 2, 4, 7 etc.

Comment: what about https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/filter-indexed.html ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `slice` function for that providing it a list of positions:

```
val list = listOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)
val positions = listOf(1, 2, 4, 7)
println(list.slice(positions))
```

Note that it prints `[2, 3, 5, 8]` because positions of list items are numbered from zero in Kotlin, so the position 1 corresponds to the second element, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Doing it as suggested with filter Indexed

```
fun main() {
    val values = listOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0)
    val filter = listOf(1, 2, 4, 7)
    val resultV1 = values.filterByIndexV1(filter)
    val resultV2 = values.filterByIndexV2(filter)

    println("Input: $values")
    println("Filter: $filter")
    println("Result V1: $resultV1")
    println("Result V2: $resultV2")
}

fun <T> List<T>.filterByIndexV1(filter: List<Int>): List<T> {
    return this.filterIndexed { index, _ -> filter.contains(index) }
}

fun <T> List<T>.filterByIndexV2(filter: List<Int>): List<T> {
    return filter.map { this[it] }
}
```

Comment: What is the need of the extension function? Isn't `filterIndexed` enough?

Comment: filter indexed is enough .. but if he wants to have it reusable a extension function might be used ..

Comment: Note that this returns items in index order, not in filter order.  (This may be what's wanted, but isn't obvious so would be worth documenting.  If so, I'd suggest making the parameter a Set, not a List, for efficiency.)  Alternatively, you could do e.g. `return filter.map{this[it]}` to get filter order, which would be faster for a random-access List.

Comment: @gidds .. i like that approach :-)